# Recover CSV-File in Jupyter that was overwritten

Tags: python, csv, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I work with JupyterLab and have accidentally overwritten an existing CSV-File in my environment.

In my environment, there was a "data.csv"-file at first which I have uploaded to my environment.
Now I accidentally executed the following line in my Jupyter-Notebook:

```
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

So the "data.csv"-File was overwritten with the content of the "df" variable (the wrong dataframe).
Is there a way to get back the old version of the "data.csv" file or is this dataset now lost?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This depends not on Jupyter but on your system setup. If your folder was synchronized in, for example, OneDrive there will probably be a file history available which you can restore.

I assume that the file was not part of a Git repo. If so, that would be the obvious solution.